# Shift image with in a static picture box

Tags: vb.net

I want to display a map on my form which i can control with the mouse. I want to be able to adjust the zoom of the map with the scroll wheel, and i want to be able to move the view around the map when I'm zoomed in, so i can look around. I want the picture box to be static, and only shift the actually image below to great the illusion of looking around the map. I'm having a lot of difficulties with this. Is it possible to move shift the picture which in a static picture box or do i have to use some kind of graphics draw to dynamically display the correct part of the map?

Comment: Zooming requires creating at least one scaled version of your image. Either you do it dynamically by redrawing it at the point of zooming, or you pre-create a list of zoomed images. As far as for panning (shifting) it, the least memory and CPU consuming would be to place an autosized picture box in a scrollable panel. Then when dragging with the mouse you would have to calculate how the panel will scroll according to the cursor's movement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you draw directly on the form or in a Panel using their Paint event. Yes, it is possible to reposition an image in a PictureBox as shown here:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _moveIt As Boolean = False
    Private _coyote As Image

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _coyote = PictureBox1.Image
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        _moveIt = True
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        If _moveIt = True Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_coyote, New Rectangle(New Point(32, 64), _
                                                        New Size(_coyote.Width, _coyote.Height)))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

But notice that the PictureBox's Image is removed (set to Nothing), so the one thing that distinguishes a PictureBox is no longer used.

To continue to use the PictureBox's Image property you would have to recreate an image each time, based on the original, and set it as the Image property. This isn't a viable approach. Just draw the image on the form or in a panel using Paint and its Graphics object.

Comment: One could always create a custom picture box that overrides/shadows the `Image` property. That way the image can be preserved without having the control drawing it.

Comment: I don't have to use a picture box, that just seem like the easy solution. Can i use the paint graphics in a panel and still change the image dynamically? Like zoom in and out and pan around the image?

Comment: @TobiasKnudsen : Of course you can, you can use any control. :)

Comment: Could you give a simple example of how to use a panel. Lets say i want a panel with an image and a button which will zoom the image?

Comment: The internet has examples of these things, and tutorials.

Comment: @TobiasKnudsen : Andy's right. We are not really here to write code for you. It happens in certain cases, but this kind of code takes a bit of time writing as one will have to fiddle a lot with it to get it right. --- Start looking into the various ways you can use the graphics class.

Comment: My posted code provides an initial example anyway, you would just use the Paint event of a Panel rather than of a PictureBox (and you wouldn't be concerned with setting an Image property to Nothing).